# Como posso obter a cor de um pixel usando python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu gostaria de saber como eu posso, usando python, obter a cor de um pixel da web? Eu estou a tentar fazer um bot e preciso que ele recolha a cor da pagina web e não de uma imagem das coordenadas seguintes:

Coordenadas - `(774,503)`

Já exprimentei a package `imagegrab` mas não funciona pq so exite para `python2`

Espero ter esclarecido o meu problema qualquer informação esta sobre o problema porfavor comentem!

Comment: Tem certeza que precisa acessar as coordenadas 774, 503 de uma imagem 81x22?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Na web sao essas as coordenadas essa era apenas a imagem para mostrar o local de onde eu queria tirar a cor nesse caso amarela!

Comment: Ponhaum pouco do código que você já tentou.
A imagem está num site? Você já tem a URL da imagem?  Sem essas informações não tem como se responder.

Comment: @jsbueno editei o meu post deforma a tentar exclarecer todas as duvidas!

Comment: Qual sistema operacional?

Comment: Oi, DeadSec, será que não seria viável, você realizar um printscreen da tela na hora com o python, e depois simplemente pegar o pixel ? Desculpa não postar uma resposta, é que eu estou no trabalho. :)

Comment: @DaviMello Acabei por descobrir que nao dava para fazer o bot como eu queria porque o python nao consegue a cor do pixel pois a camada suprior é branca !

Answer (score 1):

```
import pyautogui

pixelColor = pyautogui.screenshot().getpixel((510, 687))

#converte RGB para HEX (desnecessário se você precisa apenas do código RGB)
pixelColor = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (pixelColor)

print(pixelColor)
```

Onde está o 510 é a posição x do pixel 
Onde está o 687 é a posição y do pixel

Você também pode criar 2 variáveis antes da 3ª linha:

```
x = 510
y = 687
```

E trocar os valores de dentro da função getpixel() para (x, y)

```
pixelColor = pyautogui.screenshot().getpixel((x, y))
```

Para pegar as coordenadas x e y de onde o mouse está posicionado, use:

```
pyautogui.position()
```

Comment: Pode-se obter a documentação do pyautogui no seguinte link https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. Nela tem a seção Installation com o comando para instalar em cada SO